# How to position a def for a sum of entries in TKINTER

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get a sum of t1 and t2 after pressing button b1. However, I cannot figure out where to position the def sum(self): As it currently sits in the code I am getting the error TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' after inputting in t1 and t2 then pressing b1.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        root.geometry("1000x500")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",
                                  tags="self.frame")


        self.populate()


    def populate(self):
        l1=Label(self.frame,text="First Number")
        l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        t1=Entry(self.frame)
        t1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        l2=Label(self.frame,text="Second Number")
        l2.grid(row=1,column=0)
        t2=Entry(self.frame)
        t2.grid(row=1,column=1)
        l3=Label(self.frame,text="Result")
        l3.grid(row=2,column=0)
        t3=Entry(self.frame)
        t3.grid(row=2,column=1)
        b1=Button(self.frame,text="Click For SUM",command=sum)
        b1.grid(row=3,column=1)


def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


def sum(self):
    a=int(self.t1.get())
    b=int(self.t2.get())
    c=a+b
    self.t3.insert(0,c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could have done it very simply. The way you are doing it is extra complicated than it should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is expecting the parameter `self`. In python, class methods (unless explicitly decorated with @staticmethod) are automatically passed `self` ( the object calling the function) as the first parameter.

**Your first issue is one of indentation:** `sum(self)` is not indented and thus not interpreted as being a method of the Example class, and neither is onFrameConfigure; you need to indent both of those to be at the same indentation level as populate()

**Even after you fix that, you'll run into another problem:**
You also need to assign variables to the class when you create them in `populate(self)`, otherwise they will only exist in the scope of that function, and you won't have a good way to access them. you also need to change the command. Since you're calling a method you need to declare the appropriate namespace (self):

```
    def populate(self):
        self.l1=Label(self.frame,text="First Number")
        self.l1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        ...
        self.b1=Button(self.frame,text="Click For SUM", command=self.sum)
        self.b1.grid(row=3,column=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I made the but still showing this error: TypeError: sum() takes at least 1 positional argument (0 given)

Comment: You also need to change the command you have assigned to b1. The member functions of the class are called by self.fn(), rather than fn().

So when you create the command, it should be self.sum

Comment: I figured it out. I had command=sum instead of command=self.sum.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Once I get 15 I will come back and upvote your response.

Comment: @MelanieLauzon you can still accept the answer if it solved your question regardless of your reputation.